# A condition for matrices to commute

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Recently found an exercise for high school students as follows:

Let $A,B$ be $2\times 2$ matrices with real entries and suppose $A^2=B^2$, $\operatorname{tr}(A)\neq0$,$\operatorname{tr}(B)\neq0$. Show that $AB=BA$.

Since it only ask the case for $2\times 2$ matrix and hence we can simply bash out all the equations.

**My problem.** Does this hold for $n\times n$ matrices, or does it have a generalization?

Comment: three-way not-equals is confusing as $\neq$ is not transitive. Does $\text{tr}(A) = \text{tr}(B)$ or not?

Comment: Perhaps there is a generalisation following [The Cayley-Hamilton theorem](https://www.statlect.com/matrix-algebra/Cayley-Hamilton-theorem)?

Comment: Fixed the non-equal notation.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Does this hold for $n\times n$ matrices?

Of course not. The problem statement seems to insinuate that $A$ and $B$ may possibly not commute when one of them has a zero trace. So, suppose you can find an example in which both $A$ and $B$ have zero trace and $AB\ne BA$. Then $\pmatrix{1\\ &A}$ and $\pmatrix{1\\ &B}$ will serve as a counterexample for $3\times3$ matrices. In particular, when
$$
A_1=\pmatrix{1\\ &1&1\\ &0&-1}\quad\text{and}\quad B_1=\pmatrix{1\\ &0&1\\ &1&0},
$$
we have $A_1^2=B_1^2=I_3$ but $A_1B_1\ne B_1A_1$ over any field.

If you think about how to prove the statement in question, you will see what is special about $2\times2$ matrices. By Cayley-Hamilton theorem, we have $A^2-\operatorname{tr}(A)A+\det(A)I_2=0$ and the analogous holds for $B$. Therefore, the condition $A^2=B^2$ is equivalent to $\operatorname{tr}(A)A-\det(A)I_2=\operatorname{tr}(B)B-\det(B)I_2$. This, when coupled with the further condition $\operatorname{tr}(A)\ne0$ (we actually don’t need both $A$ and $B$ to have zero trace), simply means that $A=pB+qI$ for some scalars $p$ and $q$. Therefore $A$ can be expressed as a polynomial in $B$ and it commutes with $B$.

> Does it have a generalisation?

I don’t know any nice ones. We have seen that behind the scene, the given conditions actually effect a direct manipulation of the coefficients of the characteristic polynomial, so as to make $A^2$ and $B^2$ equal to $a_1A+a_0I$ and $B^2=b_1B+b_0I$ respectively for some scalars $a_0,a_1,b_0,b_1$ with $a_1,b_1\ne0$. If you want to generalise this for $n\times n$ matrices, you need to zero out the coefficients of $x^{n-1},x^{n-2},\ldots,x^2$ in the characteristic polynomials of $A$ and $B$ and require that the coefficients of $x$ are nonzero. These conditions can be expressed in terms of the traces of the powers of $A$ and $B$ (thanks to [Newton’s identities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_identities)), but it is hard to conceal the solution trick.

If you don’t insist on generalising the exact problem statement at hand, there is a problem in a similar style, whose result holds in every dimension:

> Let $A,B,C$ be three real or complex $n\times n$ matrices such that $AC=CA$ and $BC=CB$. If $(aA+bB+C)^n=AB-BA$ for some pair of scalars $(a,b)\ne(0,0)$, then $AB=BA$.

(See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4344507) for a proof of a similar statement.) Yet I don’t think any average high school student is able to solve this.

Answer (score 6):

Here is a counterexample in $\mathbb{R}^4$ (or $F^4$ for any field $F$ with characteristic different from 2)
\begin{equation}
A: (x, y, z, t)\mapsto (x, y, z, -t)
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
B: (x, y, z, t)\mapsto (z, t, x, y)
\end{equation}
Then $A^2=B^2=I$ but $A B \not = B A$ because
\begin{equation}
A B: (x, y, z, t)\mapsto (z, t, x, -y)
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
B A: (x, y, z, t)\mapsto (z, -t, x, y)
\end{equation}
For a more general example, let $U$ and $V$ be non colinear column vectors in $F^n$ such that $V^T U = -2$. Let $A = I + U V^T$ and $B = A^T = I + V U^T$. Then $A^2 = B^2 = I$ and $A B \not = B A$. One also has $\text{tr} A = \text{tr} B = n - 2$, so if $n\not = 2$, the non-zero trace assumption is satisfied.

Comment: In your first example, don't you have trB = 0 ?

Comment: @FlorianF It is true. You could take $B:(x, y, z, t)\mapsto (x, t, z, y)$ instead to have a non-zero trace. However in dimension 2 the theorem is that if $\text{tr}(A)\not = 0$ or $\text{tr}(B)\not = 0$ then $A$ and $B$ commute.